# Firebase not defined js error when trying to display real-time firebase db data on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a moisture sensor for my first IoT project. I am saving the data from the sensor in a real-time Firebase database. For my webpage I am using glitch.com, and I am trying to display the data from the db on my webpage. I tried coding this myself, but got pretty much nowhere. So I decided to remix an existing glitch.com "Firebase Read" project. However I am encountering a problem, it's saying: 'firebase' not defined in the following 3 lines (In the first line listed below, it's also saying config is not defined):

```
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

```
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

```
  var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("Moisture");
```

I currently have the following in my js file:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"></script> 
    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  // Initialize Firebase
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx",
    databaseURL: "xx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();


  // List to hold my moisture value
  var myMoisture = [];

  // Define database connection to correct branch, Moisture
  var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("Moisture");

  // Function that acts when a 'new child is added to the DB' - i.e. new data is added this function runs.
  myDBConn.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey){

    // The data returned from the branch is put into a variable, dataPoint
    var dataPoint = data.val();

    // Convert the 'Temp' field from dataPoint into integers, then put them into the myTemps list
    myMoisture.push(parseInt(dataPoint.Temp));

    // Add all the Temps and get the total
    var totalT = 0;
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i<myMoisture.length; i++){
      totalT += myMoisture[i];
    }

    // Create an average by dividing the sum of temps by the number of temps
    var average = totalT / myMoisture.length;

    // Update the page elements with the average and the last item (most recent) off the list 
    document.getElementById("averageT").innerHTML=average;
    document.getElementById("LiveT").innerHTML=myMoisture[myMoisture.length - 1];
  });
```

This in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"></script> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  </head> 

  <body>

    <h1>Reading from Firebase Cloud Database</h1>

    Live Moisture Reading: <a id="LiveT">---</a> <br>

    Average Temperature: <a id="averageT">---</a>



  </body>
</html>
```

And this is shown by the debugger (I don't know if this information is relevant and what it means, but maybe it's useful):

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1270:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1405:7)
    at Lws.listen (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/lws/1.3.2/node_modules/lws/index.js:81:12)
    at WsServe.execute (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/lws/1.3.2/node_modules/lws/lib/command/serve.js:296:26)
    at WsServe.execute (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/local-web-server/2.6.0/node_modules/local-web-server/lib/command/serve.js:11:18)
    at Map.start (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/cli-commands/0.4.0/node_modules/cli-commands/index.js:26:18)
    at WsCliApp.start (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/lws/1.3.2/node_modules/lws/lib/cli-app.js:9:26)
    at Function.run (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/lws/1.3.2/node_modules/lws/lib/cli-app.js:15:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/pnpm-global/1/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/local-web-server/2.6.0/node_modules/local-web-server/bin/cli.js:5:29)
```

What things could I try next?

Comment: The error Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 means that something is already running on the PORT your trying to use.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll look into this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Quick scan of the FireBase docs

I see that your FireBase import is slightly wrong:

Try changing it to:

```
  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

The docs are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, sadly it did not resolve the error.